# Does there exist $z_0 \notin \{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ such that $f(z_0) = 0\ $?

Tags: complex-analysis, infinite-product, analytic-functions, entire-functions

I am reading Weierstrass Factorization Theorem from the lecture notes given by our instructor. Here I came across a theorem which is the following $:$

> $\mathbf {Theorem} :$ Let $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of non-zero complex numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = \infty.$ If $\{p_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of positive integers such that $$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left (\frac {r} {|a_n|} \right )^{p_n + 1} \lt \infty$$ for all $r \gt 0$ then $$f(z) = \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_{p_n} (z/a_n)$$ converges in $H(\mathbb C)$ to an entire function $f.$

Here $E_p$'s are the elementary factor defined for $p =0,1,2,\cdots$ as follows $:$

$$\begin{align*} E_0 (z) & = 1 - z, \\ E_p(z) & = (1 - z) \exp \left (z + \frac {z^2} {2} + \cdots + \frac {z^p} {p} \right ),\ p \geq 1. \end{align*}$$

From here our instructor concluded that **$f$ has zeros only at the points $a_n.$**

I understand that $f$ has zeros at $a_n$ since $E_{p_n} (z/a_n)$ has a simple zero at $a_n$ and there are no other zeros. But I don't understand the fact that $f$ can't have any other zero. The infinite product is something which confuses me. Because if we have finitely many non-zero quantities their product is still non-zero but this is not true for infinitely many non-zero quantities. For instance if we take $b_n = \frac {1} {2},$ for all $n \geq 1$ then their product is clearly $0$ if we don't restrict ourselves to finitely many $n.$ Could anyone help me understanding this concept?

Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: Rudin proves (in RCA) that the product is convergent. (See Weierstrass Factorization Theorem). This implies that the only zeros of the product are the zeros of of its factors.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, let's recall a few facts about infinite products.

1. Suppose $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and define $q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+a_k)$.

> *Definition:* $\prod_n(1+a_n)$ converges if there is  $p\neq0$  such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}q_n=p$. When $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}q_n=0$, it is said that $\prod_n(1+a_n)$ *diverges* to $0$.

It is a well known fact (Cauchy criteria for infinite products) that $\prod_n(1+a_n)$ converges iff for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N_\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$\Big|\prod^k_{j=1}(1+a_{n+k}) -1\Big|<\varepsilon,\qquad n\geq N, \, k\in\mathbb{N}$$
See for example, *Apostol, T.,  Mathematical Analysis, p.p. 207.* The proof is based on the standard Cauchy criteria of sequences. If you need details about his, let me know and will provide some steps for you to complete the proof.

2. Recall that a product $q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+a_n)$ is said to converge absolutely (again $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) iff $Q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+|a_k|)$ converges. Form the Cauchy criteria above,  it is not difficult to check that if $q_n$ converges absolutely, then $p=\lim_nq_n$ exists and $p\neq0$.
3. Finally, recall that $q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+a_n)$  converges absolutely (again $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) absolutely iff $\sum_n|a_n|<\infty$. This follows from the inequality
   $$ \sum^n_{k=1}|a_k|\leq \prod^n_{k=1}(1+|a_k|)\leq \exp\Big({\sum^n_{k=1}|a_n|}\Big)$$

---

In the product $\prod^\infty_{n=1}E_{p_k}(z/a_n)$ where $|a_n|\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$ you have the estimates
$$|1-E_{p_n}(z/a_n)|\leq |z|^{p_n+1}\frac{1}{|a_n|^{p_n+1}}$$
for $|z|<|a_n|$, with $$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\frac{r}{|a_n|}\Big)^{k+1}<\infty$$ for every fixed $r>0$.  This shows that the product $\prod_nE_n(z/a_n)=\prod_n \big(1-(1-E_k(z/a_n))\big)$ converges absolutely when $E_k(z/a_n)\neq0$ for all $n$, and vanishes only if $z=a_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: The Cauchy criterion follows for the case where $a_n > 0$ for all $n$ by noting that $\prod\limits_{n} (1 + a_n)$ converges if and only if $\log \prod\limits_n (1 + a_n) = \sum\limits_n \log (1 + a_n)$ converges. From here, we can use the fact that a sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy. And the sequence here is Cauchy if and only if the Cauchy criterion is satisfied since $\log$ is continuous. To generalise, note that whenever the product converges, there is some $N$ such that $a_n > 0$ for all $n > N$. And whenever the Cauchy criterion is satisfied, there is also such an $N$.

Comment: @MarkSaving: The Cauchy criteria is more general than the trivial case $a_n>0$. The statement I consider is for $a_n\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-1\}$.

Comment: Correct, and you can generalise to this case by noting that in either case, there is some $N$ such that $Re(a_n) > 0$ for all $n > N$.

Comment: @MarkSaving: sure, but there is no need to to so since the proof of the Cauchy criteria is rather straight forward and does not require to separate real and complex parts.

Comment: I don't know how recalling the above things the answer follows immediately. I want to know why can't $\prod\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty} E_{p_n} (z_0/a_n) = 0$ for $z_0 \neq a_n,$ for all $n \geq 1\ $? I already aware of the result what you have discussed. Although I have some doubts about convergence of the infinite product. In Conway's book on complex analysis it is not mentioned that the infinite product diverges if it goes to $0.$ Please have look at the definition given in page no. $164.$

Comment: Because unless on of the factors is zero, the product will converse to a point that is different from zero. That is what (2) and (1) tells uou